# CSS Background repeat round to one direction only in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I wanted to combine `backround-repeat` `round` and `repeat-x`. On many different web pages I saw that `background-repeat: round` equals to `background-repeat: round round` that means *Round times repeat to X and round times repeat to Y*, isn't it so? That's why I thought that writing `round no-repeat` would repeat to one direction only.

My code repeats to all directions. I'm using `Firefox 30.0`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style="background-image: url('bg.png'); background-repeat: round no-repeat">
</body>
</html>
```

Is it browser specific or should I do other way if there is a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it should work like you thought.

The problem is that Firefox doesn't support the value `round` yet. Then, the rule is ignored, and the value used is the default `repeat`.

You can see browser support in [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat#Browser_compatibility):

- Chrome: no
- Firefox: no ([bug 548372](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=548372))
- IE: 9
- Opera: 10.5
- Safari: no

As a workaround, I suggest using a fallback value:

```
background-repeat: repeat no-repeat; /* fallback for old browsers */
background-repeat: round no-repeat;  /* for browsers that support it */
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/G6wa9/)

Answer (score 0):

According to [the MDN page on `background-repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat), and [this issue on Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=548372), `background-repeat: round;` is only supported on IE 9 and Opera. Because Firefox does not recognize the `round` keyword, it is defaulting to the default `background-repeat: repeat;`.

It is not supported in Firefox 30, and it's currently unknown when it will be implemented in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

It is browser specific since only a couple of browsers do support it. My suggestion to work-around is below:
I would only use `background-repeat:repeat no-repeat`.

As for the "round" vs "round round" this is something we see a lot. Let me explain:
If only one argument given eg. "repeat" it applies in all directions.

If two arguments is given, these defines the X & Y direction eg. "repeat no-repeat"
the first indicates the x, and the second the y.

If three is given, we have "top", "sides" and "bottom" eg. "margin: top sides bottom"

If four, we have "top, right, bottom, left"(clockwise) eg. "margin: top right bottom left"

Comment: @imustafin I read your question more thoroughly and i saw what you actually ment to do, removed the "cover" bit